# HeapSort counting element comparisons

Tags: java, algorithm, heap, heapsort

i use HeapSort to sort an array of integers.
And i want to know the number of element comparisons for an arraylength of 4.
Now when i use a global variable it counts 6 for the worstcase. Well i thought HeapSorts worst-case performance is nlog2(n). So it should be 8 right?
So when i go to http://www.allisons.org/ll/AlgDS/Sort/Heap/ and insert my array, it also says 6. But what does this faktor of * 0,75 do in this case?
Thanks so far

Comment: Asymptotic worst case running time only come into effect for large values of N, for smaller arrays (like a tiny one of size 4) the constants of the algorithm often overshadow any asymptotic running time.

Comment: You cannot conclude anything from asymptotic complexity for specific values of `n`.